# Functionalities between calling rpc methods

Tags: scala, client, grpc, rpc, zio

Im trying to alter ZIO's [example code](https://scalapb.github.io/zio-grpc/docs/basics/) to fit what I want, but ran into a problem. I want to implement functionalities between different rpc calls, but I can't seem to get it to work, since in below example, only the while loop, `rcpMethod3()` and `rcpMethod4()` gets executed, whereas `rcpMethod1()` and `rcpMethod2()` doesn't.

I want to execute all of the `rcpMethod`s and the while loop.

```
object Client extends App {
  val clientLayer: Layer[Throwable, ClientZLayer] =
  ClientZLayer.live(
    ZManagedChannel(
      ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8980).usePlaintext()
    )
  )
  
  // rcp methods
  def rcpMethod1(): ZIO[ClientZLayer with Console, Status, Unit] = {
    for {
      response <- ClientZLayer.rcpMethod1(Greeting("Hi"))
      _ <- putStrLn(s"""Greeted: "${response.name}".""")
    } yield ()
  }
  
  // Run the code
  final def run(args: List[String]) = {
    (for {
      _ <- rcpMethod1()
      _ <- rcpMethod2()
    } yield ()).provideCustomLayer(clientLayer).exitCode

    while(condition) {
      // bla bla
    }
  
    (for {
      _ <- rcpMethod3()
      _ <- rcpMethod4()
    } yield ()).provideCustomLayer(clientLayer).exitCode
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ZIO` data type is a functional effect. A functional effect is a description of a workflow. This is why we have the `run` method at the end of the world. This run method executes the provided `ZIO` effect.

All the `rcpMethodN` methods are `ZIO` effect, so they are just a description of running workflow. If you want to run these effects sequentially you should compose them using `for-comprehension` or `flatMap` like this:

```scala
for {
  _ <- rcpMethod1()
  _ <- rcpMethod2()
  _ <- rcpMethod3()
  _ <- rcpMethod4()
} yield ()
```

The `while(condition){ ... }` is another mistake in your code. You should introduce these loop structs with `ZIO` data type. For example:

```scala
for {
  _ <- rcpMethod1()
  _ <- rcpMethod2()
  _ <- ZIO.effect(???).repeatWhile(condition)
  _ <- rcpMethod3()
  _ <- rcpMethod4()
} yield ()
```